# How do I disable webpack in a Chrome extension build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webpack, eval

I got Selenium IDE sources [from here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide) and built them with `yarn build` (because that's what's written in repository's travis.yml file). The result is a huge .js file which contains multiple lines each starting with `eval()` and each time a very long string is passed into `eval()` and it looks like each source file from the repository is transformed into a long string which is then passed to `eval()`. AFAIK this is called bundling.

I guess this is because the package.json file contains this line:

```
{
    "scripts": {
         "build": "webpack",
    },
}
```

I want to debug the code and I guess my best chance is disabling bundling so that I get the original code put in the build result. For this I need to replace `webpack` with something else. I searched for a while and there's lots of guided on how to enable webpack but I cannot find anything about how to disable it.

How do I disable webpack such that original JavaScript sources get into build results?

Comment: I don't see the `"build": "webpack",` in the package.json there, but the `eval`s are there to help with debugging, see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/. You can disable it with `devtool: 'none'` if you can find the webpack config file

Comment: That line is inside "recorder" folder https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/blob/master/packages/side-recorder/package.json

Comment: Look in https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/blob/master/packages/side-recorder/webpack.config.babel.js, try adjusting `devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'eval',` to `none`

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you. Why was this closed as a duplicate of some other question which doesn't look the same to me?